# What is missing in OpenAI Gym registration?

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I get `ValueError: xxx not found in gym registry, you maybe meant` when trying to register a custom environment in stable baselines 3. I tried the following commands:

```
apt-get install swig cmake ffmpeg freeglut3-dev xvfb
git clone --recursive https://github.com/DLR-RM/rl-baselines3-zoo
cd rl-baselines3-zoo
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/MatePocs/gym-basic.git
cd gym-basic
pip3 install -e .
cd ..
cd rl-baselines3-zoo
python3 train.py --algo td3 --env basic-v0 --eval-freq 1000 --save-freq 5000
```

The result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 107, in <module>
    raise ValueError(f"{env_id} not found in gym registry, you maybe meant {closest_match}?")
ValueError: basic-v0 not found in gym registry, you maybe meant CubeCrash-v0?
```

Do you see which is the mistake?

Comment: if I add `import gym_basic` inside `train.py` then it resolves this problem. But it gives next problem `train` tries to find some `hyperparameters` for this environment but it has predefined `hyperparameters` (in folder `hyperparameters`) only for standard environments - it is not ready to run with non-standard environment

Comment: I check `train.py --help` and first problem can resolve `train.py ... --gym-packages gym_basic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be resolved with `--gym-packages gym_basic`

```
python3 train.py --algo td3 --env basic-v0 --eval-freq 1000 --save-freq 5000 --gym-packages gym_basic
```

But then it shows other problem with `hyperparameters`.
For standard environments it has predefined tunned `hyperparameters` in folder `hyperparameters`.
For `--algo td3` in `hyperparameters/td3.yml`.
But there is no parameters for `basic-v0`

If I duplicate other parameters and use name `basic-v0`

```
basic-v0:
  n_timesteps: 300000
  policy: 'MlpPolicy'
  noise_type: 'ornstein-uhlenbeck'
  noise_std: 0.5
```

then (theoretically) it resolves this problem

... but it gives next problem.

`train` want to get `env.action_space.shape[0]` and `basic-v0` doesn't have `[0]` in `shape`

So all this many need more changes.

Answer (score 2):

Gym doesn't know about your `gym-basic` environment—you need to tell gym about it by importing `gym_basic`.

For the `train.py` script you are running from RL Baselines3 Zoo, it looks like the recommended way is to import your custom environment in `utils/import_envs.py`. You should append something like the following to that file.

```py
try:
    import gym_basic
except ImportError:
    gym_basic = None
```

You then need to set the hyperparameters for the environment for the agent you are using—in this case, td3—in the relevant file under the `hyperparameters` directory. You can look at the existing environment hyperparameters in the `hyperparameters/td3.yml` file to get a sense of what hyperparameters must be specified. You can then set your hyperparameters for the `basic-v0` environment like this.

```yaml
basic-v0:
  # Hyperparameters go here...
```

*However*, you should note that, according to the [Stable Baselines 3 documentation](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/algos.html) documentation, td3 does not support discrete action spaces, so training will likely fail even after you specify your hyperparameters.

You might want to try a different algorithm—the steps should be the same as those described above. Just specify a different algorithm when running `train.py`, and be sure to specify the hyperparameters in the relevant file under the `hyperparameters` directory.